# Who are these Bat-family members?

Tags: comics, dc, batman, character-identification

[This page has a wallpaper](http://prowinwall.net/wallpaper/bat-family/) which seems to have a recent (pre-New 52) Bat-family wallpaper. I recognize almost everyone, but two of these people confuse me - I'm not sure who they are.

[image: Here's the picture itself, in case the link dies.]

I recognize the characters, from left-to-right, as follows:

- Barbara Gordon (Oracle)
- Huntress
- Batwoman? (Not certain about her)
- ???
- Batgirl III (Cassandra Cain)
- Catwoman
- Batman (Bruce Wayne)
- Batman (Dick Grayson)
- Red Hood (he may have changed his name? Jason Todd)
- Robin (Damian Wayne)
- ???
- Batman (Terry McGuiness)
- Alfred

Am I correct about the characters I've identified? And who are the three I'm not sure about?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- **Barbara Gordon**
- **Huntress**
- **Batwoman**
- **Batgirl IV**
- **Batgirl III**
- **Catwoman**
- **Batman** (Bruce Wayne)
- **Batman** (Dick Grayson)
- **Red Robin** (Tim Drake)
- **Robin V** (Damien Wayne)
- **Red Hood**
- **Batman** (Terry McGuiness)
- **Alfred Pennyworth**

The two you can't identify are [Stephanie Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanie_Brown_%28comics%29) who served as the first female Robin for a time, as well as Spoiler, and Bat-Girl.

[image: Stephanie Brown]

The second is [Red Hood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Todd) aka Jason Todd.  The person you initially identified as Red Hood is actually Red Robin (Tim Drake).

[image: Jason Todd]

Comment: Ok...so is that Batgirl IV then?  Also, if Red Hood (Jason Todd) is next to Batman Beyond, then who is pictured between Dick and Damian?

Comment: Aha, your edit clarified things!  Thank you.

Comment: I just edited my answer with every character's name including the two unidentified

Answer (score -2):

- Batman (Bruce Wayne)
- Batman (Terry McGinnis)
- Red Robin (Tim Drake)
- Robin (Damian Wayne)
- Red Hood (Jason Todd)
- Nightwing (Richard Dick Grayson)
- Alfred Pennyworth
- Catwoman (Selina Kyle)
- Batgirl IV (Betty Kane)
- Batgirl III (Barbara Gordon)
- Batwoman (Kathy Kane)
- Huntress (Stephanie Brown)
- Flamebird

Comment: Could you [edit] some evidence in to why these are these characters? Especially where your list contradicts the other answer's list like on Flamebird. Also in the future could you try and not shout everything... it makes it more difficult to read.

Comment: I don't know any version of Stephanie Brown being Huntress. Didn't you mean Helena Wayne/Bertinelli instead?

Comment: It might also help if you followed the same pattern as the original, left to right from the far left. Unless, of course, Flamebird looks like an English Butler these days.