# Can we identify characters from Cartoon Network?

Tags: character-identification

After looking at questions like

[Who are these classic DC characters?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121259/83884)

[Who are these people at Deadpool's wedding?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/119845/83884)

[Who are these Bat-family members?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/31873/83884)

I have thought of asking an identification question on a list of characters from Cartoon Network.

[image: Image of characters from Cartoon Network shows]

Many shows here have sci-fi touch to them.

This image is shared often on social media.

I could identify some characters.

- Powerpuff Girls
- Tom and Jerry
- Dexter
- Johnny Bravo
- Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles
- Baby Looney Tunes
- Scooby Doo
- Shaggy Rogers
- Courage the Cowardly Dog

What are all the characters in the image?

Comment: I have voted to close this as off-topic as some these character are SFF, but most are not.

Comment: I see Barney (Rubble, not Fife).

Comment: To the right of Johnny Bravo are Ed, Edd and Eddy

Answer (score 5):

Starting from top left:

- [Captain Planet and the Planeteers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Planet_and_the_Planeteers): Captain Planet with Kwame, Wheeler, Linka, Gi and Ma-Ti

[image]

- [Looney Tunes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looney_Tunes): Tweety, Wile E. Coyote, Sylvester, Foghorn Leghorn. Bellow them, Elmer Fudd, Daffy Duck, Bugs Bunny, Porky Pig
- [Dudley Do-Right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley_Do-Right)
- [Beetlejuice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetlejuice_(TV_series))
- [Courage the Cowardly Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courage_the_Cowardly_Dog): Eustace Bagge, Muriel Bagge, and Courage
- [The Powerpuff Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Powerpuff_Girls): Buttercup, Bubbles and Blossom
- [Droopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droopy)
- [Tom and Jerry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_and_Jerry)
- [Boo-Boo Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo-Boo_Bear)
- [Space Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Ghost): behind Boo-Boo Bear
- [Yogi Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Bear)
- [Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles](https://cartoonnetwork.fandom.com/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles): Michelangelo, Leonardo and Raphael
- [Birdman and the Galaxy Trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birdman_and_the_Galaxy_Trio): Birdman
- [Cow and Chicken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cow_and_Chicken): Cow and Chicken
- [The Flintstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flintstones): Fred Flintstone, Dino, Wilma Flintstone, Pebbles Flintstone, Bamm-Bamm Rubble, Betty Rubble, Barney Rubble
- [Scooby-Doo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby-Doo): Shaggy and Scooby
- [The Smurfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_(TV_series))
- [The Jetsons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jetsons): Rosie, George, Jane, Judy, Elroy and Astro the dog
- [Tiny Toon Adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Toon_Adventures)
- [Animaniacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animaniacs)
- [Pinky and the Brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinky_and_the_Brain)
- [Johnny Bravo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Bravo)
- [Ed, Edd n Eddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed,_Edd_n_Eddy)
- [2 Stupid Dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Stupid_Dogs): The Little Dog and The big Dog
- [Magilla Gorilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magilla_Gorilla): Magilla Gorilla and Ogee

Comment: IIRC I haven't seen The Smurfs on CN ever .. but who knows

Comment: @RigaCrypto smurfs: maybe on some repeat or other countries not sure

Comment: @RigaCrypto Smurfs aired on Cartoon Network in 1992. Before Cartoon Network changed to CN.

Comment: @SteveHarrington It is Tiny Toons from the show Tiny Toon Adventures. They’re furry, they’re funny, they’re Babs and Buster Bunny, Hampton, Plucky, Elmira, Furball, Montana Max, Dizzy, Go-go the dodo, the roadrunner, and the female skunk whose name I can’t remember.